# How to create a grid view in mvc4 without using scaffolding techniques

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I just need to create a grid view with edit delete create operations without using scaf folding techniques is this possible in mvc4 ??

Comment: Scaffolding is not a magic, it is just some predefined code which Visual studio generates for you according to some rules. So yes, any code can be written without using scaffolding, and grid view is not an exception.

Comment: I just need a sample code if possible give me some examples please sir

Comment: First google result: [http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/597253/Using-the-Grid-MVC-in-ASP-NET-MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/597253/Using-the-Grid-MVC-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC we use WebGrid instead of ASPX Grid View... Here is the link which you can refer to understand WebGrid [Click Here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/E2S9150113-Enhancing-WebGrid-with-Insert-Update-and-Delete-Operations.html)

> [This may also help](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/create-an-editable-webgrid-in-mvc4-to-implement-crud-operati/)